# GRASP, who is resposible for notifying lifecycle events?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, parsing

I'm creating a **XAML parser**. During the parse process the objects of a tree are instantiated using reflection (their Types are discovered in runtime).

The problem comes because the clients of my parser need to know about events that happen during the construction (and setup) of each object, and **I don't know who to assign this responsibility**: the parser? the instance itself?

In WPF, I know there is an interface that is called `ISupportInitialize` that can be implemented. **The parser checks whether objects implement it or not to call the appropriate methods** (`BeginInit`, `EndInit`).

As a side note, I find it a bit dirty to check if an object implements an interface. It makes anyone wanting to receive such notifications implement a specific interface.

**Extra details:**

This is the flow with the lifecycle events.

The parser will discover tags like `<Button Content="Hello World" />` that means that it will have to look for the Button type and instantiate it. This is the order.

1. "Begin Init" is the signal when the instance has just been created
2. "Set Properties" is when the parser is about to assign all properties of the object (specified in the markup). It's Content="Hello World", in this case.
3. "Associated to Owner". This signal is produced when the instance is assigned to its parent. Like the case when the Button is child of a Window.
4. "End Init". This signal should arrive when the process is complete.

Comment: Can you put some code here? What objects of a tree are instantized, why you use dynamic types and what events does your system emit?

Comment: Please, see the updated question :) Sorry, I wrote "dynamic" but I mean that the types of the instances are discovered while parsing. The parser knows what type to instantiate when it finds a tag in the XAML. It's explained above, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the Informational Expert principle says, that a responsibility is to be assigned to the object with the highest possible knowledge of the subject.

In your case, this is the parser. But that doesn't mean your parser should call your client's code directly. Yes, it should be event emitter, but concrete event emitter implementation can be chosen by you.

I recommend using [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or [PubSub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern to notify the clients.

This way your parser emits the event by the use of a specialised class, that is responsible for event broadcasting.